# Flashing border

Tags: android, eclipse, button, border

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Button states with Background as AnimationDrawable in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299219/button-states-with-background-as-animationdrawable-in-android)

How to create a button that, when pressed, will have a flashing border appear around it? I also would like to know if I can start the flash from a slow tempo to a quicker tempo within a second or two.