# How to set animation for button background

Tags: android

I have button and I have two pictures green.png and red.png. How to achieve that when button is visible to change button background every 500 ms ( green.png=>red.png=>green.png=>red.png...) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299219/button-states-with-background-as-animationdrawable-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use **AnimationDrawable**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Hope it help you!