# Start Animation automatically without the need of click

Tags: android, animation

i know this question has been asked several times but i just cant figure out where to place the code and keep getting errors. its a basic fade in animation on a image which i want to be invisble at first and then fade in. thanks in advance
my animation xml followed by java of the class.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" 
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
      android:duration="4000"/>
 </set>
```

**Java:**

```
package com.example.whattodo2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Title extends Activity {
Button reset, rts;
ImageView title;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_title);
    reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                       double rand = Math.random();
                       if(rand < 0.5){
                           Intent reset1 = new Intent(Title.this, MainActivity.class);
                           startActivity(reset1);
                       } else {
                           Intent reset2 = new Intent(Title.this, Question36.class);
                           startActivity(reset2);
                       }
                }
            });
    rts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rts);
    rts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent rts=new Intent(Title.this,Rts.class);
                    startActivity(rts);

                }
            });

         final Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.animation);
         a.reset();
         final ImageView rImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.title);

         RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
         layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override public void onClick(View v) {
         rImage.startAnimation(a);
         func(); //A call to the function.

         }
         });


}

protected void func() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.title, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: it is not clean what you are asking.

Comment: Did you try putting the code in `onResume()`?

Comment: just put your code  rImage.startAnimation(a); at onCreate() Method.

Answer (score 1):

remove  rImage.startAnimation(); from the click listener.

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.animation);
ImageView rImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.title);
rImage.startAnimation(a);
```

Comment: doesnt work ... loadAnimation gives an error inside on Click listner for some reason

Comment: As i said, remove it from the onClick listener, you've said that you want to start the animation without the need for a click. Also it would be really helpfull to provide a stacktrace of the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library to complete the animation:

```
$.with(rImage).attr("alpha", 0f).animate("{ alpha    : 1.0 }",
                    new AnimationOptions("{ duration : 4000,
                                            easing   : accelerate }"));
```

Answer (score 0):

See you cannot start a animation in onCreate, because it is not something that is sticked to main ui, Search more

Here is a link that will help you.

[Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063920/how-to-start-animation-in-oncreate-in-android)

Comment: I used slide down animation in my application,I want whenever open the application the animation will be worked automatically without buttons..give me the solution..