# android animation not working

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I'm trying to animate an image view with a simple fade in but when I run it in my emulator it simply does nothing. Any idea what is happening or what I am doing wrong?
I tried to reproduce the example in this [website](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm), but somehow it's not working.

**Here's a sample of my XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:duration="2000"
    >
    </alpha>
</set>
```

---

**Here's a sample of my code:**

```
protected void onStart () 
    {
        super.onStart();



    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
    ImageView logo = new ImageView(this);

    int margem_px = 50;
    float density = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int margem_dp = (int)(density*margem_px);

    Resources res = getResources();
    layout.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.branco));


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(margem_dp, margem_dp*2, margem_dp, margem_dp);
    logo.setLayoutParams(params);



    logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.pc_apps_logo_white);

    logo.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    logo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    logo.setAlpha((float) 0);

    layout.addView(logo);




  Animation anima = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.myfadein);
    logo.startAnimation(anima);


  } 
}
```

Comment: confirm in settings that if device animation is off or not

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063920/how-to-start-animation-in-oncreate-in-android

Comment: Yes animation is on, also it's not working on a real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just **remove** this line & here you go:

```
logo.setAlpha((float) 0);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you a lot! I thought that the alpha would be modified by the animation even if I set it.