# How to add Frame Animation to an ImageButton including Button State change handling?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-xml, android-imagebutton

I want to add animation-list to a selectors xml file which in turn is added to an  ImageButton. On default state, I want the animation to be played and on pressed state, I want some other image to be displayed. My code is working for button state changes but the animation didn't work on default state.
Actually I am reading Android

**anim_virus.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attackvirus0" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attackvirus1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attackvirus2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attackvirus3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attackvirus4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attackvirus5" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attackvirus4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attackvirus3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attackvirus2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/attackvirus1" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

**button_state_virus.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/attackviruspress"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/attackvirusfocus"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim_virus" android:state_enabled="true"/>
</selector>
```

And my image button tag and its parameters are:

```
<ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#00000000"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
      android:src="@drawable/button_state_virus"
      android:id="@+id/button_infect"
      android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_virus"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just a `drawable` background animation you can do:

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_infect);
imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim_virus);
```

if you want to `.start()` the animation, do this:

```
((AnimationDrawable) imageButton.getBackground()).start();
```

if you want to `.stop()` it, do this:

```
((AnimationDrawable) imageButton.getBackground()).stop();
```

But, to get a `StateListDrawable` animation from your `ImageButton`, you have set the `StateListDrawable` as your `android:background` attribute in XML.

```
StateListDrawable background = (StateListDrawable) imageButton.getBackground();
Drawable current = background.getCurrent();

if (current instanceof AnimationDrawable) {
  imageButton = (AnimationDrawable) current;
  btnAnimation.start();
}
```

So this code gets the background from the `ImageButton`, it then defines the background as a `drawable` depending on the state you're in. If that current state is an `instanceof AnimationDrawable` i.e. your `animation-list` then it'll play the animation.

**Edit**: changed from error in comments

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{AttackPlanetActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Credit for edit: [Button states with Background as AnimationDrawable in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299219/button-states-with-background-as-animationdrawable-in-android)

Comment: I had tried use AnimationDrawable like you have mentioned. But it leads to application crash with the error description  'E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{AttackPlanetActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity'.  If I set anim_virus to the button and remove the android:src parameter, I can able to see the animation with AnimationDrawable start()